# Calling method within itself

Tags: java, loops, recursion, methods

I wanted to make an input which accepts numbers from 1 - 10 and prints the range.

I need to check if the input is an integer (check), check if the range is 0-10 (check), and if it's not any of those things, to ask the user again. So, a recursive method?

Currently I have this:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.InputMismatchException; 

public class FinalTest {
  public static void main (String [] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int k = 0;

    System.out.print("int - ");

    try {
      k = in.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
      System.out.println("ERR: Input");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    if(k <= 10 && k > 0) {
      for(int j=1; j <= k; j++) {
        System.out.println(j);
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("ERR: Oob");
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to replace the "System.exit()" so that it re attempts to ask the user for input again.

calling `main();` produces an error.

How do I correctly call the main method in this case?

Comment: I'd suggest a loop.

Comment: You don't need recursion for this. Just use a loop. See: [The `while` and `do-while` Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: Stick it in a loop. Or alternatively put the logic into a function and call the function recursively.

Comment: For what it's worth you can use a recursive method for this but you shouldn't. A simple loop would suffice `while(don't have valid answer){ask for answer}`

Comment: Yes loop it: While (incorrect){}

Comment: By the way: the use of `return` is always better than `System.exit(int)` if it is possible - and in this case it is possible, you should replace it.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept ;-)

Comment: Just for the record: if would be really answering your question on howto invoke main() --- then your question is missing essential parts. Meaning: when you want us to help with an error, then put up a [mcve] that includes the code creating the error, and the error message itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two choices here:

- actually create a method and call that
- simply use a loop

Loop could go like:

```
boolean askForInput = true;
while ( askForInput ) {
  try {
    k = in.nextInt();
    askForInput = false;
  } catch ...
    print "not a number try again"
}
```

But beyond that: you **still** want to put this code into its own method. Not because that code should call itself, but for clarity reasons. Like:

```
public static int askForNumber(Scanner in) {
  ... code from above
  return k;
}
```

And to answer your question: you do not want to use *recursion* here. You want to *loop*; and yes, *recursion* is one way to implement looping, but that is simply overkill given the requirement you want to implement here.

And for the record: when creating that helper method, you can actually simplify it to:

```
public static int askForNumber() {
  while ( askForInput ) {
    try ...
      return in.nextInt();
    } catch ...
    print "not a number try again"
  }
}
```

Beyond that: you typically use recursion for *computational* tasks, such as computing a factorial, or fibonacci number, ... see [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/) for example.

Comment: Hey, appreciate the answer. Very helpful. Just one thing - why isn't this working? 

`boolean askForInput = true;  
    while ( askForInput ) {  
      System.out.print("int - ");   
      try {   
        k = in.nextInt();  
        askForInput = false;   
      } catch (InputMismatchException e) {  
        System.out.println("ERR: Input");  
      }  
    } `

Comment: It just keeps printing ERR. Shouldn't it prompt for input every time?
Heres the pastebin url, for easier reading: https://pastebin.com/vPrXw3MX

Comment: @py9 I followed that link and put it into a simple main method ... it prints "int-" ... I enter a number, hit enter ... program ends. Thus: please put a [mcve] there - something I can download **as a whole** and run to repro the problem.

Comment: the issue is when you dont input a integer, but a string. Shouldn't it go to the beginning of the loop and ask for an input again? (since the askForInput is still true). Here's the full code: https://pastebin.com/GAykyrwj

Comment: @py9 OK. I have to admit I simply had a wrong understanding how nextInt() works. So you might want to go with your previous try/catch code. I am honestly to busy today to start making experiments with that scanner myself.

Answer (score 1):

for the part of the recursive method printing a range:

```
public void printAscending(int n) {
  if (n > 0) {
     printAscending(n - 1);
     System.out.println(n);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using recursion is just too much for something that simple and would probably be more expensive. You can add a while loop around your scanning bit until the entered value is valid. I would also put the printing loop out of the while to not have to test a condition before printing since if you get out of the while loop, it means number if valid. You could test just the -1 value to exit process.

```
public class FinalTest
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int k = 0;

        do
        {
            System.out.print("int - ");

            try
            {
                k = in.nextInt();
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e)
            {
                System.out.println("ERR: Input");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        while(!(k>0 && k<=10) && k!=-1);

        if(k!=-1)
        {
            for(int j=1; j<=k; j++)
            {
                System.out.println(j);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Bye Bye.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so what I personally do when I need to use recursion is I create a separate function/method for it. And when I need to restart the method, I just call it within itself. So it would be something like this:

```
private void recursiveMethod() {
// do stuff . . .
if (yourCondition) {
    //continue to next piece of code
} else {
    recursiveMethod();
}
```

}

But in big projects, try to stay away from recursion because if you mess up, it can